# How to make scene using only specyfic colors

Tags: rendering, color, compositing-nodes

I want to make my scene in some particular colors (or even different shades of only one color), similar to the picture below.[image]

I was trying to make render black and white and then use postproduction, but it didn't give this result. Can someone help how to achieve that?

Comment: It must be possible to change the colorimetry in the Video Editor? Or Compositing?

Comment: Possible solutions may be 1-Filmic (from github) has a greyscale look under filmic log transform. 2-Use a color ramp in compositor over a mask on desired passes. (ASC-CDL  node should be enough though) What do your current shader/ compositing setups look like?

Comment: In Blender compositing I made only set up to controle mist, some blurs, background, beams, glossy control and some color correction. https://i.ibb.co/rZm07LS/compositing.png, further postproduction was made in other software (photoshop / Aurora HDR)

Comment: Up: but I'm not so familiar with these programs so it was mostly fail.